# Delete contents of a cell at the end of a VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, email

This is my first question ever and it comes as a result of looong tries and fails to solve it myself or through online research.

I wrote a code (i.e. used the ones I found online) to make an automatized e-mail sent from Excel whenever "YES" is written in column M.

Please find the codes below:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range        
    Set KeyCells = Range("M2:M1000")
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then
            Call SendmailAuto

        End If
    End Sub
```

And

```
    Sub SendmailAuto()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim RelDate As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim dateCell, dateCell1 As Date

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    OutApp.Session.Logon
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    On Error GoTo cleanup
        For Each RelDate In Range("K2:K" & lastRow)
        If RelDate = "" Then GoTo 1
        dateCell = RelDate.Value
        dateCell1 = Cells(RelDate.Row, "I").Value
        SendMailCell = Cells(RelDate.Row, "M").Value
        If SendMailCell = "YES" Then
              Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
                On Error Resume Next
                With OutMail
                    .To = Cells(RelDate.Row, "AD").Value & ";" & Cells(RelDate.Row, "AE").Value & ";" & Cells(RelDate.Row, "AF").Value
            .subject = "A new submission deadline set"
            .body = "Dear " & Cells(RelDate.Row, "R").Value & "," _
                    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "A new submission deadline for " & Cells(RelDate.Row, "G").Value & _
                    " is now set to " & dateCell & "  by  " & Cells(RelDate.Row, "L").Value _
                    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
                    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Regards," & vbNewLine & _
                    "XYZ"
            .send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If

    1:  Next RelDate
    cleanup:
        Set OutApp = Nothing
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

It all works fine, but the problem I have is that in case there are more than one "YES"es in the M column, more than one e-mail is sent. I would like to have a line in the code that would clear the contents of column M after each e-mail.

In other words - I write YES, e-mail gets sent, YES disappears. I put in a YES in the next row, an e-mail is sent, and this YES disappears too.

I tried all Clear.Contents, Delete.Contents and all those, but nothing seems to be working.  It either crashes, or keeps deleting all columns from M on.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this instruction after .send and before the end with

```
Cells(RelDate.Row, "M").Value=""
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped! I was sure I was doing it at the wrong place, since I kept putting it at the end of the whole script!

Comment: could you then validate the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you get an error, because you do not reference the workbook and the worksheet. If the column M is in the first worksheet in the workbook, try it like this:

```
thisworkbook.sheets(1).Columns("M:M").ClearContents
```